# java.lang.NullPointerException in boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'm trying to assign the boolean array value for some specified number but I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here's my code

```
 Boolean[] apps = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    apps[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: Boolean[] apps = null; => apps is null...

Answer (score 2):

you aren't initializing the array. the `apps` variable is never anything different than NULL.

```
Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
apps[i] = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out as below:

> ```
>    Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];
>     for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
>     apps[i] = false;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

you did not initialize the array. the apps variable is never anything different from NULL.

So a call to a member at position `i` can not be found.
Hace a look at [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to understand

```
Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    apps[i] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not initializing your array so it crashes because it is null

```
 Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.length; i++)
    apps[i] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiante the array
apps = new Boolean[30];

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized/ allocated memory for apps[]. That's why you are getting `NULL Pointer Exception.`

```
Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];

for (int i = 0; i < apps.length; i++){
        apps[i] = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a loop to initialize all elements, you could either declare it as a `boolean[]` instead, as the default value of a primitive `boolean` is `false`:

```
boolean[] apps = new boolean[30];
```

or you could use `Arrays#fill(Object[], Object)`:

```
Boolean[] apps = new Boolean[30];
Arrays.fill(apps, false);
```